# Plotly Dash not showing graphs when connect with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pandas, plotly-dash

I am connecting Plotly dash with SQL Server like this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                  'Server=DESKTOP-B4NA1S5;'
                  'Database=Al-Hawama;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

query = "SELECT * FROM compItemCust"
sales = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

The data stored in `sales` is in the form of pandas dataframe. When I do analysis on it, the graphs wont show. But if I again change this sales dataframe into a csv file locally, then it shows all the graphs.

Can anyone please help? Why won't the graphs show from the database directly? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a double quote on the line starting with `query=`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I have updated it. By mistake didn't include here in this question. The original problem still remains.

Comment: Share some more info with which the problem can be debugged. What does the value of `sales` look like? Are the columns for example the same as with your local csv? Can you share sample data and the code that plots the graphs so the problem can be reproduced? Also be sure to run your Dash app with `debug` set to `True` so you get helpful error messages.

Comment: Thank you Bas for valuable suggestions. I found the problem. Actually the datatype of columns was changed when fetched directly from the database. So I have to change the data type of columns and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution. The problem was that when you fetch the data directly from the database, the data type of the columns change. So I had to change the data type of the columns and match it with the one present in local csv data frame in order to get the results.